# Designing Android layout in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Hey guys i want to create this layout https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAiTf.jpg in android studio. Can you give me idea how to do this kind of layout? Im newbie in android.

Comment: This is not how SO works dear. You should try something, and if hit a roadblock, then ask here. This is not a "Ready to serve" platform :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to create the UI if you want. I can help you by just to give an idea in below image. Hope it will help you.

[image]

Comment: Oh, thank you. I want to create a profile page similar in the below image. Can you create me. Sorry i dont i understand a little bit of your provided image but anyway thank you very much.

Comment: nice @Farya upvote for this

Comment: @madara09 first search about Tab fragment, then forward step by step, take your time and try it :) you will create it.

Comment: Ok thank you. Im little confused in everything in android studio so im gonna try my best.

Comment: Best of luck :)